# How can I add lemmatization to AWS Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

We used to use a lemmatizer with Sphinx search, but have now moved to AWS Elastic search.  How can we add a lemmatizer to aws elastic search so when we search for "be", "are" is matched as well?

Comment: Looking for the same, it is quite surprising that ES doesn't still support lemmatization!